# Exception minimum y maximum progress bar

Tags: c#

Al realiza mi proceso de lectura, con este va avanzando el progress bar, o al menos asi debe ser,el problema es que todo mi proceso termina exitosamente y el progress bar no va al mismo ritmo, este termina un minuto despues, y despues de eso me manda una exception:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'Value of '31' is not valid for
>   'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'. Parameter
>   name: Value'

```
if (progressing_Files.InvokeRequired)
    {
     progressing_Files.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { progressing_Files.Value++; })); //en esta marca la exception
    }
```

Tengo definidos mi minimo y maximo de la siguiente manera:

```
progressing_Files.Minimum = 0;
progressing_Files.Maximum = Files_Descompress.Length + Files1.Length + Files2.Length;
```

Que causa la exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando:

```
progressing_Files.Minimum = 0;
progressing_Files.Maximum = Files_Descompress.Length + Files1.Length + Files2.Length;
```

Tenemos:

```
if (progressing_Files.InvokeRequired)
{
     progressing_Files.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { 
         // Preguntamos si es menor que el maximo
         if(progressing_Files.Value < progressing_Files.Maximum) {
             progressing_Files.Value++; 
          }
     }));
}
```